# Move all values inside vectors in C

Tags: c, vector

i'm writing a code for a project, in which i need to move values inside a vector! For example, i have a completely "null" vector:
`[0][0][0][0][0]`

Then i will add a value to it's first position: `[10][0][0][0][0]`!

Ok, now i need to add again a value to the first position, but i cant lose the value already there, i want to move it to the right, like:
`[0][10][0][0][0]`

To put the new one there: `[5][10][0][0][0]`

And then do this again, move the 5 and the 10 to the right again, to add a new one in the first, and so on!
I hope i was clear enough!

---

**@EDIT :**

Its done guys! **Thanks to everyone** that tried to help!

The problem was solved using @AkashPradhan function:

```
void changeposition(int* vetor, unsigned int size, int valor)
{
    unsigned int i = size - 1;
    for(; i > 0; --i)
        vetor[i] = vetor[i-1] ;
    vetor[0] = valor ;
}
```

Thanks @AkashPradhan! The function worked perfectly with my code!

Comment: Isn't that C++? I have to do the project only in C!

Comment: @Skepller: Why do't you just add the next value to a later position, such that you'd have `[10][5][0][0][0]`?

Comment: @ryyker: that is the original term. Has been replaced in newer standard by more common "array". However, oldies like me still use it interchangeably sometimes.

Comment: When you "add" new values to the front, and shift the other data, is it the last value in the "vector" that will be dropped? And you might want to take a look at the [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) function.

Comment: Skepller: could you please clarify if, by "vector", you mean an array, or an arbitrary ordered type which could also be implemented by a list (for instance).

Comment: @Olaf i mean an Array! Sorry!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'll look up this funcion, thanks! And in regard of the last value, in this case, if the array is completely filled, it wouldn't move the values, and say that the array is full to the user!

Comment: @TamásSzabó Because the work is supposed to be done like that! It would be much easier if i could just put it in the next position!

Comment: @Mat: Ah, true --  never mind :-S (But jut implement the same thing that a C++ vector does for `insert` and that'll be a solution.)

Comment: Question seems to have garnered attention - The downvote(s) seems odd.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, i actually dunno why, only a couple minutes after i post it, it already had 3 downvotes, lol

Comment: @Skepller - My guess is that you posted no example code to show what you have tried. This might have been initial reason for down votes.  (posting what you have tried is really preferred).  ***By the way***, you have described (in your post and comments) a stack.  A stack is conceptually a container that holds a limited number of things, from 0 to n.  When you place the first item on the _top_, the first position is filled, the rest are empty.  When you place the second item on, then the first move down by one, the second is now on top, and so on until the stack is full, no more can be added..

Comment: ...only removed.  As items are removed, the lower positions are emptied, one by one until the stack is completely empty.  Have I described what you want correctly?  There is a ***[piece of code I found here](http://www.cprogramto.com/c-program-for-queue-using-stack/)*** (although buggy) could be easily modified to do what you want to do.  It uses two _stacks_ (as opposed to your one) and it needs a few minor adjustments to do what you have described, but give it a try.

Comment: Yes, i should've putted some examples of what I've tried so far, maybe that's the reason... And yes, that's basically what i wanted! Except that in this, i dont need to remove anything, only add, or clear the whole array if asked by user. And the problem is already solved by Akash Pradhans function, but i will see this code anyway, maybe i can get my code a little better! Thanks @ryyker

Comment: Skepller: you might want to change to tag from vector to array (this will clarify the question pretty much).

Comment: If you really need a stack, you can get along very well without copying items. Just add/remove to/from the end of the array and have the index of the last position in an extra variable (maybe a struct?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Linked List and add to the front node or you could use an array and shift the elements by one position for each insertion.

In this case, I would recommend using a Linked List as the insertion routine will not involving moving every element. However if frequent random access to elements in required, use the array approach.

```
void insert_front(int* array, unsigned int size, int value)
{
    unsigned int i = size - 1;
    for(; i > 0; --i)
        array[i] = array[i-1] ;
    array[0] = value ;
}
```

Note that the routine does not check if you are inserting more elements that the size of the array.

Comment: hm... It almost worked!


when the array is null, like: [0][0][0][0][0]

and you add a value: [12][0][0][0][0], its cool, but when you try to add a new one, it goes like this:
[10][12][12][12][12]

and if you try to add a new one, it will delete the last one, like this: [5][10][10][10][10], the 12 is already gone.

And so on, only keeping the first and second ones!

Comment: Edited. Should be fixed now @Skepller.

Comment: Jesus, @AkashPradhan, i love you bro, i had to make some of modifications in my code, create some vars to make the call for this function to work, but it worked perfectly! Thanks A LOT!

Comment: A linked list would have massive performance issues with indexing. Also, I support @ryyker s suggetion to use memmove(). These are most times highly optimized.

Comment: @Olaf I did write about it that if random access is required, the array approach is way better than Linked List.

Comment: Well, right, sorry. That was a bit hidden, didn't expect this major issue appear there. Working on being less trigger-happy. I still hold using memmove()

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this as a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), in which case you don't need to copy the elements all the time. An example of it would be:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t bufferSize;
    size_t currentPos;
    int *data;
} ring_buffer;

void init_buffer(ring_buffer *buffer, size_t N)
{
    buffer->bufferSize = N;
    buffer->currentPos = 0;
    buffer->data = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
}
void free_buffer(ring_buffer *buffer)
{
    free(buffer->data);
}
void push_buffer(ring_buffer *buffer, int value)
{
    ++buffer->currentPos;
    if (buffer->currentPos >= buffer->bufferSize)
        buffer->currentPos = 0;

    buffer->data[buffer->currentPos] = value;
}

int get_buffer(ring_buffer *buffer, size_t pos)
{
    size_t dataPos = buffer->currentPos + pos;
    if (dataPos >= buffer->bufferSize)
      dataPos -= buffer->bufferSize;

    return buffer->data[dataPos];
}
```

or you could use a linked list as suggested by @AkashPradhan.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own array, implement push operation, shift right data when push a new element. This implementation would delete the stale element.

```
typedef struct Array {
  int *data;
  size_t len; // current size of the array
  size_t cap; // capacity of the array
}Array;

Array * new_array (size_t cap_){
   Array *arr = (Array *)malloc(sizeof(Array));
   arr->cap = cap_;
   arr->len = 0;
   arr->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * cap);
   return arr;
}

void free_array(Array * arr){
    if (arr->data != NULL) 
        free(arr->data);
    free(arr);
}

void push(int x, Array *arr) {
  int ptr = std::min(len, cap) - 2;
  for(int i = ptr;i >= 0;i --) {
    arr->data[ptr + 1] = arr->data[ptr];
  }
  arr->data[0] = x;
  len = std::max(cap, len + 1);
}
```

Update :  You can also use  Tamás Szabó 's answer to avoid data movement.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't have constructors/destructors in C, only in C++

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write the corresponding function yourself then it can look the following way

```
size_t move( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n++ != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = n; --i != 0;  ) a[i] = a[i-1];
    }

    return n;
}
```

And you could use it the following way

```
size_t n = 0;

n = move( a, n );
a[0] = 10;
n = move( a, n );
a[0] = 5;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
printf( "\n" );
```

Otherwise you have to use standard C function `memmove` the following way

```
memmove( a + 1, a, n * sizeof( int ) );
++n;
```

where n is the current number of actual elements in the array.